Error: FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists! ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?
estoy aprendiendo a programar Java en netbeans SDK y JDK, en mi caso, tengo un problema con la base de datos y volver a abrir el Jframe form.
Cuando cierro el formulario donde guardo datos para el Database sigue con normalidad, pero cuando vuelvo a querer abrir ese mismo formulario, me marca un error y no abre diciendo que la base de datos ya existe.
Les agradeceria si podrian ayudarme a encontrar o solucionar el problema, tengo entendido que debo cerrar la base de datos pero aun no encuentro como.
Gracias y disculpa por las molestias
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Exito al conectar
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists!
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:502)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:222)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:215)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:202)
    at com.mycompany.prueba.Conexion.conectarfirebase(Conexion.java:29)
    at com.mycompany.prueba.igu.CreaReseña.<init>(CreaReseña.java:15)
    at com.mycompany.prueba.igu.Main.jButton3ActionPerformed(Main.java:128)
    at com.mycompany.prueba.igu.Main$3.actionPerformed(Main.java:48)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)```


Difícil decir sin ver el código. El mensaje de error es bastante claro. Diría que estás mandando a crear una base de datos que ya existe y, dado que no pueden haber 2 bases de datos con el mismo nombre, falla. Sugiero que leas [ask] y que adjuntes el código que provoca el error.

Ya encontre la respuesta a mi problema, decidi que conectara la base de datos desde el formulario principal.

Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta.. Por favor mira [answer]
